# Decoding %E6%B0%94%E6%97%8B%E5%93%88%E5%88%A9.txt to a valid string

Tags: c++, http, boost

I am trying to decode a filename*= field of content disposition header. I get a string something like:

```
%E6%B0%94%E6%97%8B%E5%93%88%E5%88%A9.txt
```

What I have figured out that replacing % to \x works fine and I get the correct file name:

```
气旋哈利.txt
```

Is there a standard way of doing this in C++? Is there any library available to decode this?

I tried

```
boost::replace_all(name, "%x","\\x");
std::locale::generator gen;
std::locale locl = gen.generate("en_US.utf-8");
decoded_data = boost::locale::conv::from_utf( encoded_data, locl);
```

But it prints the replaced string instead of chinese characters.

```
\xE6\xB0\x94\xE6\x97\x8B\xE5\x93\x88\xE5\x88\xA9.txt
```

Any Idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: At worst you can do `scanf("%%%02X", &var)` in a loop (checking return value of course)

Comment: The character `'\'`  is an escape character only in string literals and character literals.

Comment: "Is there a standard way of doing this in C++?" -- No. "Is there any library available to decode this?" -- Yes. If you're parsing HTTP headers, that suggests to me that you're probably using a relevant library already to make the requests (although it is of course possible you're not). Which one? (Perhaps Boost itself?) It would be best to have a library that plays with that nicely.

Comment: Tried from_utf but the result is same. @hvd

Comment: You need a function named something like urldecode(). If your library has nothing similar, you can google up an implementation in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing escape code like `"\xE6"` only work in string and character *literals*, not generally in strings. That's because it's handled by the compiler when it compiles the program.

However, it's not very hard to do yourself, using a simple loop that check for the `'%'` character, gets the next two characters and convert them to a number and use that number as a "character".

Comment: How about a filename with real % in it? E.g. test%file.txt

Comment: @ShivendraMishra If the name is URL-encoded, then the % character should *definitely* be encoded too. You can add some safety though by checking if the two characters after the `'%'` are valid hexadecimal digits.

Comment: That literally means I am writing a library for it. Anyway thanks for answer!

Comment: '...and convert them to a number and use that number as a "character".'

Nope: that will be a byte. The result of %-decoding is a sequence of bytes, and that needs to be decoded using UTF-8.

See <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#examples>.

Comment: The real % character can be encoded as either %% or %hh where hh are hex digits.